# On a page with a meta refresh (with time=0 seconds) run the analytics javascript in the <Head>?

Tags: javascript, html, page-refresh

If I have the Google Analytics .js call at the end of the  tag, and I have a meta refresh tag (refresh in 0 seconds) to redirect the page (to another site), will the .js run OK every time or is there a chance the page will somehow redirect before the .js runs?

(My understanding is that the .js essentially runs asynchronously so the answer should be Yes, the .js will always run. But wanted to check.)

Comment: why won't you  test it? anyway I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

firstly look 
time=0 seconds,so,
it may/may not cause an execute , probably 0th chance (No chance)
 the browser should reload the current page  in 0 seconds

and some Drawbacks to Using Meta Refresh Tags

**Meta refresh tags have some drawbacks:**

Meta refresh redirects have been used by spammers to fool search engines. So search engines remove those sites from their database. If you use a lot of meta refresh tags to redirect pages, the search engines may decide your site is spam and delete it from their index. It’s better to use a 301 Server Redirect instead.

If the redirect happens quickly (less than 2-3 seconds), readers with older browsers can’t hit the “Back” button. This is a usability problem.

If the redirect happens quickly and goes to a non-existant page, your readers may get stuck in a loop without seeing any content other than a 404 page. When this happens, most people simply give up and leave rather than trying to figure out where you were trying to take them.

Refreshing the current page can confuse people. If they didn’t request the reload, some people can get concerned about security.

why wint you use javascript with a time out?

```
    <script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
   setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.href = "tea.html"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex:                  tea.html)
    }, 2000); //will call the function after 2 secs.
    </script>
```

Comment: If we set a 2 second time out, is the google analytics .js more likely to run if we're doing the delay/refresh with .js (above) than with a meta refresh?

Comment: ya,ofcourse may be!, just place the script below the google analytics .js script load ,and try to give some time , why dont you use JQuery/ajax/load instead of a redirect ?

Answer (score 1):

The asynchronicity of Google Analytics works against you here. As soon as the browser sees the `<meta>` tag redirecting it to another page, it'll start navigation to that new page. If that page starts loading before Google Analytics is done, the Analytics ping won't go through.

Don't depend on Google Analytics working on pages that the user won't be looking at for at least a few seconds.