# Redirect after the session finishes in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hey guys am really a noob in php...I just want to make a redirect after the session ends..So i have came to know that without js this cant be implemented..So i have modified the code with the help of my friends

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['logintime'] = time(); 
echo 'this page needs to be redirected in a minute'
?>


 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">

$(function(){
var loginTime = <?php echo $_SESSION['logintime']; ?> 

var testSession = setInterval(function(){
    var currentTime = Date.now() * 1000; 
    if((currentTime - loginTime) > 60) { //here 60 denotes a minute

        <?php  session_start();

session_unset();
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
?>
        window.location.href = 'www.google.com'; // redirecting process
    } 
}, 1000); 
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code runs without errors ..but it isnt redirecting after 60 seconds..

Any guides to make this code work correct would be really appreciated..Thanx

Comment: Why don't you just use PHP for this? You can do a redirect after an amount of time with the header function.

Comment: No the idea that you can use js to handle the session is wrong. Just use php

Comment: @codehx i have used php too..as mentioned here,.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537874/session-times-out-and-auto-redirect........but it still didnt work

Comment: @Blaatpraat can u pleae post a working code as an answer it would be helpful..

Comment: On top of your code, after <?php, you do this: header( "refresh:60;url=pageAfter60Seconds.php" );. Oh, and this really needs to be on top, before <html> (even session_start() needs to be before <html>).

Comment: You can't launch PHP Code into a javascript condition. The session will not be destroyed after 60 seconds if it's your intention. You must understend how server and client works before this implementation.

Javascript code it's executed in the browser or client. If you want capture a client event like timeout and make a server action like session destroy you must launch an AJAX request from client to the server.

Comment: @Curlas how can i do this with pure php ??..can you please post the code as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it goes in the  section of your html:
Using html only

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content ="5; url=http://www.target.com/">`

5 is the number of seconds. Now you can replace 5 with some PHP generated value.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content ="<?php echo $limitTime(); ?>; url=http://www.target.com/">`

Comment: Can you please edit your answer ..cuz i dont get what ur saying ,..i would accept the answer if u could edit it and  give me the code

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content ="5; url=http://www.target.com/">`. Replace 5 with some PHP function or variable. Or just change 5 to the number of seconds you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in Javascript use following syntax

```
setInterval(function () {window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'}, 60000)
```

In php you can use header method to redirect url

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com")
```